# aws - get count of failed deployments of AWS CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codepipeline

I want to add a widget in CloudWatch Dashboard for number of failed pipeline deployments per day. I am able to check pipeline status in CodePipeline > Pipeline-name>History.

But how do we get Failed deployments in Cloudwatch? Is it possible ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you deploying with codebuild or codedeploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CodeBuild and this is your main point of failure, then the Build Failed metric is available in Cloudwatch Dashboards directly.

Otherwise, you can look into using an SDK of your language of choice and access the api commands for this bit: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-view-cli.html and parsing the history at a regular interview into logs that you can then add to your dashboards

Comment: I am using CodePipeline. The later option will be useful, thanks!